# javascript how to close child window on end

Tags: javascript, video, window.open

I have a window in javascript that opens a child window to play a video. The only purpose of the child window is to play the video and nothing else

javascript Code:

```
locationstr = targetvideostr + ".mp4"   // example: locationstr = "video232.mp4"
videowindow = window.open (locationstr, "") // open new window
```

the child window opens fine and the video starts automatically and plays perfectly. However, I want the child window to close itself automatically after the video play has ended.

Some browsers close the child window automatically after the video play has ended, but others don't do this and leave the window open. (chrome doesn't close the window after the video has ended while an android default browser does).

Can I check from the parent to see if the video ended? can I set an event in the child window to make it close itself?

Thanks for any ideas or help.

Comment: How do you close the child window? please add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact (reading or writing properties, and execute functions) with the child window if it is on other domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 **onended** event handler

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.onended = function(e) {
    videowindow.close();
}
```